# How to set default value in li and update li from click event in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have 2 li in my one component. I am using a single method to bind 1st li and 2nd li.
case 1) In this method, I have 4 student details. So in 1st li, I want to show the 1st student details0 index[0] the data is in the same sequence[3,2,1,0] and in 2nd Li, I want to show all students data.

case 2) when i click any student in 2nd li i want to show these student data into the 1st Li.

below is my code 
my ts file code :-

```
public get selectedStudent(): Student {
    return this._dashboardService.selectedStudent;
  }
```

My Html code

Li 1st code

```
<div class="studentmenu-2-0">
  <ul class="nav align-items-center justify-content-md-start justify-content-between" *ngIf="account && students">
    <li class="col-9 col-xl-auto col-lg-10 col-md-9">
      <div class="{{singleStudent==selectedStudent && highlightStudent?'hoveffect':''}}">
        <div class="student_info">
          <div class="media">
            <span class="d-inline student-photo mr-1"><a (click)="setStudent(singleStudent)"><img [src]="singleStudent.imageUrl ? getStudentFaceImage(singleStudent.imageUrl):tempDpImage" /></a></span>
            <div class="media-body align-self-center">
              <span class="d-inline student-name mr-1"><a (click)="setStudent(stud)"><span>{{singleStudent.firstName}}</span>,</a></span>
              <span class="d-inline student-class mr-1">{{singleStudent.className}} - {{ singleStudent.sectionName}},</span>
              <span class="d-inline student-school mr-1">{{singleStudent.schoolName}}</span>
              <span class="d-inline student-school mr-1">{{singleStudent.schoolId}}</span>
              <span class="d-inline student-photos" *ngIf="!isHeartsOnly"><i>({{(selectedStudent.photos && selectedStudent.photos.list)?selectedStudent.photos.list.length:0}} photos)</i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>         
  </ul>
</div>

LI 2nd code 

<div class="col-12">

  <div id="collapseBasic" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
    <perfect-scrollbar class="scrollbar-div" [config]="config">
      <li *ngFor="let stud of students">
        <div class="{{stud==selectedStudent && highlightStudent?'hoveffect':''}}">
          <div class="hovlink">
            <a (click)="setSingleStudent(stud)"><img [src]="stud.imageUrl ? getStudentFaceImage(stud.imageUrl):tempDpImage" /> 
          </div>                        
        </div>
      </li>
    </perfect-scrollbar>
  </div>
</div>
```

i create a new method to fill 1st LI

```
public get singleStudent(): Student {

     return this._dashboardService.account.students[0];    
  }
```

Kindly help is me some have solution.

Comment: Show complete code or create a stackblitz, here some `methods` and `variables` are not properly understood. like `setSingleStudent(stud)`, `setStudent(stud)`  etc.

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati thank you to reply. See I have added one more method from this metho i can get single student detail. Now my change is that when i click any student from 2nd li same data will be displayed in 1st li.

Comment: still what you have added `setSingleStudent` and `setStudent` method is not clear, please create a sample stackblitz code and share link

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati setSingleStudent  this method is set to single student data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to change the implementation, for use with Reactive Forms, and use FormArry for the `<li>`.
With Reactive Forms, you can set a default value and change any value in FormArray in the ts file.

Comment: can you explain me with example/

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is because `get singleStudent()` always returns first element of array.

Instead of this you can show values from `selectedStudent` which gives the current selected student object.

so initially set first element as `selectedStudent` in `ngOnInit()`. 
and use then `selectedStudent` as as below

```
<div class="studentmenu-2-0">
  <ul class="nav align-items-center justify-content-md-start justify-content-between" *ngIf="account && students">
    <li class="col-9 col-xl-auto col-lg-10 col-md-9">
      <div class="{{singleStudent==selectedStudent && highlightStudent?'hoveffect':''}}">
        <div class="student_info">
          <div class="media">
            <span class="d-inline student-photo mr-1"><a (click)="setStudent(selectedStudent)"><img [src]="selectedStudent.imageUrl ? getStudentFaceImage(selectedStudent.imageUrl):tempDpImage" /></a></span>
            <div class="media-body align-self-center">
              <span class="d-inline student-name mr-1"><a (click)="setStudent(stud)"><span>{{selectedStudent.firstName}}</span>,</a></span>
              <span class="d-inline student-class mr-1">{{selectedStudent.className}} - {{ selectedStudent.sectionName}},</span>
              <span class="d-inline student-school mr-1">{{selectedStudent.schoolName}}</span>
              <span class="d-inline student-school mr-1">{{selectedStudent.schoolId}}</span>
              <span class="d-inline student-photos" *ngIf="!isHeartsOnly"><i>({{(selectedStudent.photos && selectedStudent.photos.list)?selectedStudent.photos.list.length:0}} photos)</i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>         
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi All i create a new method

```
public get singleStudent(): Student {
    var studentId = this._dashboardService.selectedStudent.userID;
    for (let i in this._dashboardService.account.students) {

      if (this._dashboardService.account.students[i].userID == studentId)
        return this._dashboardService.account.students[i]
    }
  }
```

and bind this method in 1st LI. My problem is resolved.

```
<div class="studentmenu-2-0">
          <ul class="nav align-items-center justify-content-md-start justify-content-between" *ngIf="account && students">
            <li class="col-9 col-xl-auto col-lg-10 col-md-9">
              <div class="{{singleStudent==selectedStudent && highlightStudent?'hoveffect':''}}">
                <div class="student_info">
                  <div class="media">
                    <span class="d-inline student-photo mr-1"><a (click)="setStudent(singleStudent)"><img [src]="singleStudent.imageUrl ? getStudentFaceImage(singleStudent.imageUrl):tempDpImage" /></a></span>
                    <div class="media-body align-self-center">
                      <span class="d-inline student-name mr-1"><a (click)="setStudent(stud)"><span>{{singleStudent.firstName}}</span>,</a></span>
                      <span class="d-inline student-class mr-1">{{singleStudent.className}} - {{ singleStudent.sectionName}},</span>
                      <span class="d-inline student-school mr-1">{{singleStudent.schoolName}}</span>
                      <span class="d-inline student-school mr-1">{{singleStudent.schoolId}}</span>
                      <span class="d-inline student-photos" *ngIf="!isHeartsOnly"><i>({{(selectedStudent.photos && selectedStudent.photos.list)?selectedStudent.photos.list.length:0}} photos)</i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col-3 col-md-auto ml-md-2">
              <div class="hovlink">
                <a (click)="AddNewKidPopup()" class="playBut"><span class="d-inline" style="position: relative;"><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="28px" height="28px" viewBox="0 0 213.7 213.7" enable-background="new 0 0 213.7 213.7" xml:space="preserve"><circle class="circle" id="XMLID_17_" fill="none" stroke-width="7" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="106.8" cy="106.8" r="103.3"></circle> </svg><img src="//res.cloudinary.com/klassaktcontent/image/upload/v1534852393/klassakt/svg/plus.svg" /></span><span class="add-image-text">Add kids</span></a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```